# How to run a SSIS Package which has a file based source and a target

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a dtsx file which i saved on my desktop.

It grabs a particular file(Source file (CSV)) and concatenate with the other file(Target file (CSV) as an appending manner . How can I run this DTSX? I just want this to be run on a regular basis without using sqlserver as it has nothing to do with the server.

I created this using a import and export data wizard in sql server 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run SSIS Packages standalone via DTEXEC or by double clicking on the package to run the "Execute Package Utility" (DTEXECUI).

These would need to be installed which you do so by installing SSIS **and** the SQL/Server workstation tools.

You can do this via the Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS) as well, though this would give the workstation the ability to modify the package as well.

Comment: When i save the package, I only see a file called "concat.dtsx" .  when i double click it, it open from Visual Studio. I am still trying to understand if i am missing anything here. When i created it from import export wizard it works fine and ran fine for the first time. And I chose to save the file and ended up with the above named file.

Comment: You've got BIDS installed then. If you right click it and select `Open With...` you should see `SQL Server 2008 Integration Services Package Execution Utility` as an option. That will run the package standalone.

Comment: I am afraid, I do not see that, however how could I run this on a different machine which does not have SQL server ? In Simple, can we run this dtsx file using a batch file?

Comment: You cannot run Packages without installing supporting software as outlined in my answer.

Comment: Ok, So the DTSX to run, installing SQL SERVER is a prerequisite

Comment: The reason the DTSX will not run in BIDS is due to the fact that BIDS requires a solution/project file associated to be able to run.  It you have a DTSX by itself, it will not allow you to execute in BIDS.  If you have SSIS installed on that machine, it will allow you to right click and run without a SLN or DTPROJ file.

Comment: you may just be able to copy the two executable mentioned above instead of installing the entire ssis components localy