# How to run a SSIS Package which has a file based source automatically

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a similar issue as this question:  [How to run a SSIS Package which has a file based source and a target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278118/how-to-run-a-ssis-package-which-has-a-file-based-source-and-a-target/).  At first, there was no known program to open the dtsx package (my package grabs a table from one server and places it on another).  I did some digging and found the DTEXECUI program file, and now it does open the Execute Package Utility, but it doesn't populate the Package Source (file) or Package Name (Desktop\xxx.dtsx).  How can I get it so that double-clicking the file just executes the SSIS package - or at least populates the names for the file I clicked on?  Thanks in advance.
[image: DTEXCUI]

Comment: Is integration services installed on the machine you are trying to execute the package on?

Comment: It is... never used it before, though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that since Windows didn't automatically create that association for you, the default is missing some parameters for the executable (because that program *should* open with those fields populated).

Try this:

1. Download [Default Programs Editor](http://defaultprogramseditor.com/) and run it
2. Click `File type settings`
3. Click `Context menu`
4. Locate `.dtsx` in the list and click Next
5. Click the `Open` list item and then `Edit Selected Command` [image: dpe edit]
6. The path should look something like `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\DtExecUI.exe" /F "%L"` - your path to the DtExecUI may be different, but of special note is the `/F "%L"`
7. Click `Next` and then `Save Context Menu`

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot download anything as it is a company computer.

Comment: @TWaller : Were you able to find any workaround for this issue ?

Comment: You can also fix it through the registry:
-open regedit
-Find 'DtExecUI.exe'
-open the key 'shell' - 'open' - 'command'
-and the '(Default)' REG_SZ value is something like point 6 ("%L" might be "%1"), and it's probably missing the /F (if the app is opening but not showing the file you double clicked).
(You might continue Find and see something like 'dtsx_auto_file', and do the same)
(Visual Studio 2019 Community edition)